# Angular and Mongoose - Cant access some user value. Others appear fine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Im creating a comments system and im trying to add values to the view such as the text, userName, timePosted and userProfileImageURL but the only one that wont appear is the userProfileImageURL.

I think the problem is with the controller function but it could be somewhere else altogether.

```
 /**
 * Comment middleware
 */
exports.commentByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
    Comment.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, comment) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!comment) return next(new Error('Failed to load Comment ' + id));
        req.comment = comment;
        next();
    });
};
```

or Here Possibly

```
/**
 * List of Comments
 */

exports.list = function (req, res) {

    var id = req.dealId;
    console.log('Log - ' + id);
    Comment.find( )
        .sort('-created')
        .populate('user', 'displayName')
        .exec(function (err, comments) {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(comments);
            }
        });
};
```

What does the 'user' and 'displayName' parameter in this function do?

Can i add the 'userProfileImageURL' also to the returned data somehow?

Im using the profileImageURL value like this. display name is showing but not the profileImageURL

```
<img ng-src="{{post.user.profileImageURL}}" alt="{{post.user.displayName}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * List of Comments
 */

exports.list = function (req, res) {

    var id = req.dealId;
    console.log('Log - ' + id);
    Comment.find( )
        .sort('-created')
        .populate('user')
        .exec(function (err, comments) {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(comments);
            }
        });
};
```

Just have to delete the displayName parameter and it will send the whole user object.